# Write from textfield to array for uitableview objective c iphone

Tags: iphone

What i want to do is have a textfield on the screen and a table below it, when the user enters something into the textfield, i'd like to write that value into an existing array, which is being used to populate the table? Can someone help me out with this one please?

Thanks alot

Comment: Do you want to do this as the user types in the textfield or do you have a button or something which will trigger this action?

Comment: To be honest i hadnt thought of that but i imagine they will press the text field, the keyboard will pop up, they enter their value and then press "done", thats when the value appears at the bottom of the table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not typically the place for people to write code for you.

That said, here's an example.

http://drop.io/blnnhnt/asset/example-zip

Notes:
- Uses Core Data to demonstrate persistent store.
- Uses standard UINavigationController, with two dynamically added UIBarButtons